# Automatic Wi-Fi/LTE switch based on signal strength on iPhone

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

If Wi-Fi is turned on, then, AFAIK, my iPhone will connect to any available network even if the signal is very weak and inferior to LTE.

Is there a way to make the iPhone automatically connect to Wi-Fi **only** if the Wi-Fi signal is stronger than the cellular network signal?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

---

iPhone 5s, iOS 9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

If you leave wifi on, it will automatically connect to whatever wifi spot you're set up to connect to. This is different from wifi assist, where your phone will switch from wifi to lte if wifi signal is less.

Comment: I didn’t realize this Wi-Fi Assist function existed. Thank you. However, as I checked, it has actually been turned on all along on my iPhone, and yet my problem (bias in favor of Wi-Fi over LTE even if the Wi-Fi signal is very weak) still persists.